# Decide with proof whether linearly independent over F

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, field-theory, vectors

Consider the following vectors 
w1=(1,1,1,1)
w2 = (1,0,1,0)
w3 = (1,1,2,2)
w4 = (-1,1,4,1)
Decide with proof whether the 4 vectors are linearly independent.
I am unsure of how to do this

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of linear independence?

Comment: To test for linear independence of $n$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, you can simply form a matrix using those vectors and find the determinant of it.  If the determinant is zero then they are dependent.  If the determinant is nonzero then they are independent.  This is an application of a more general result about independence of vectors and the rank of a matrix formed from those vectors, often seen via row reduction.

Answer (score 0):

To decide if the four vectors $(1,1,1,1)^T, (1,0,1,0)^T,(1,1,2,2)^T,(-1,1,4,1)^T$, you need to show that $$c_1\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1} + c_2\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0} + c_3\pmatrix{1\\1\\2\\2} + c_4\pmatrix{-1\\1\\4\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}$$ only has the trivial solution $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = 0$. The left-side can be rewritten to yield $$\pmatrix{c_1 + c_2 + c_3 - c_4\\ c_1 + c_3 + c_4\\c_1 + c_2 + 2c_3 + 4c_4\\ c_1 + 2c_3 + c_4} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0},$$ which we can write as a linear system $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 0\\1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0},$$ from which you can use elementary row operations to find the reduced-row echelon form to determine the solution.